# Yii - Extending Controller or CController?

Tags: controller, yii, class-design

I need to create a class where we should have same methods shared with all my controllers, or almost all anyway.

So, I was looking for extending controller, but THEN, I notice that `Controller Class` already extends another class `CController`.

I'm confused.

Should we create our own class and **extend** `CController`, or **extend** `Controller`, or **USE** `Controller` class anyway ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your common/shared methods in **Controller** , this class is created for that purpose only (that is your class, do whatever you want to do). no need to create another class.

Comment: I believe that as well, but here, a master Yii member didn't choose that path... and I'm wondering why. :) http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10427-ajax-clientscript/

Comment: never faced such problems. That Yii member was not insisting to create multi level inheritance( 's he ?), but to simply use his class. I would just copy his ZController code into my **Controller** class.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little difference between them; Controller is just a child class of `CController`.

In test applications, it is used to provide additional variables into all controllers derived from Controller. For instance, it's used for setting of `$breadcrumbs`, `$layout` and menu `$variables` for a layout view file.

It's a good practice to extend `YII` base classes (starting with 'C' symbol) in your project - base classes won't be touched by `YII` framework updates and code would be more decoupled.

Answer (score 0):

Controller is just a children class of CController.
In this class code ralated $breadcrumbs, $layout and menu $variables for layout defined.
If you use CController instead of controller you in SiteController.. you will get error.